# proof verification: If $f:G \rightarrow H$ is group homomorphism, and $H$ is abelian, then $G$ is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

If $f:G \rightarrow H$ is group homomorphism, and $H$ is abelian, then $G$ is abelian.

Is that statement correct? Here's my attempt of proof:

Let $a,b \in G$, then: $ab=f^{-1}f(ab)=f^{-1}f(a)f(b)=f^{-1}f(b)f(a)=f^{-1}f(ba)=ba$

Is this correct? I relied on first on $f$ being group homomorphism, then $H$ being abelian.

Comment: I think you need $f$ to be injective, otherwise this is false.

Comment: The trivial homomorphisms generate a lot of counterexamples.

Comment: You also relied on $f$ being invertible.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand my mistake now.

Comment: What you are trying to prove is not true in general. You need an injective homomorphism